# What does $X(\omega)$ mean in the expected value definition?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

In my stochastic syllabus I have the following definition:

> If $\Omega$ is at the most countable and the random variable $X$ has an expected value, then: $$ \mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{\omega \in \Omega}X(\omega)\mathbb{P}(\omega)$$

I'm not sure if I understand the notations here. What does $X(\omega)$ mean? I think $\omega$ is the result of a random experiment but I'm not sure about $X(\omega)$.

Comment: $X(\omega)$ is the value of the event $\omega \in \Omega$ induced by $X$. Remember: every random variable is just a (measurable) function from the sample space $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So in a way $X(w)$ describes the set of all countable outcomes?

Comment: $X(\omega)$ is the real number associated with an event $\omega \subset \Omega$. Example: consider a coin flip, and suppose I get paid 5 dollars if it's heads, and I lose 5 dollars if it's tails. In such a case, $\Omega = \{H, T\}$, and the random variable representing my payment is given by $X(\omega)$, where $X(\{H\}) = 5$ and $X(\{T\}) = -5$. Assuming both $\{H\}$ and $\{T\}$ are equally likely, we have $\mathbb{E}[X] = X(\{H\})(0.5) + X(\{T\})(0.5) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\Omega$ is the set of all possible outcomes of the random experiment. $X$ assigns a value, i.e., a real number, to each of these outcomes. So, for a given outcome $\omega$, the corresponding value assigned by $X$ is denoted by $X(\omega)$.